# IOS Background Push: {"reason":"ExpiredProviderToken"}%

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I'm studying a special case of remote notifications - Background push. These are silent notifications (User is not notified unlike a regular notification) which will be sent to the app in user's device by the APNS. Upon receiving the background notification, app is woken up by iOS and granted 30sec of background execution time.

I have a sample release app (changed in scheme settings, Debug -> Release) installed in my iPhone through Xcode. I'm following [this page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/sending_push_notifications_using_command-line_tools) to send push notfications from the command line (not using a server).

There are two kinds of APNS - development and production.
First, I'm using development server which, according to [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns#2947606), has the following address

> api.sandbox.push.apple.com:443

Everything works and my app is able to receive background notifications.

```
< HTTP/2 200 
< apns-id: 5B89055E-044B-4739-3247-D89B096DAED9
< 
* Connection #0 to host api.sandbox.push.apple.com left intact
```

Then, I wanted to test using production server, which has the following address,

> api.push.apple.com

Communication with APNS failed with the following error

```
< HTTP/2 400 
< apns-id: B6879B0F-9AF1-4090-B185-48FAD223300E
< 
* Connection #0 to host api.push.apple.com left intact
{"reason":"BadDeviceToken"}%
```

According to [this post](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/689857) in Apple forums, it's because, the value of APS environment field in .entitlements file is 'development'. So, I uninstalled the app, changed APS environment to 'production', cleaned, rebuilt, installed app in phone and updated the new device token in the curl command (in [this page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/sending_push_notifications_using_command-line_tools)). But I still get the same error - {"reason":"BadDeviceToken"}% .

Not sure what's wrong.

Is it that it's not possible to use production APNS with apps installed from Xcode, even if it's a release binary?

Comment: You can only use the production APNS endpoint with a released app installed from the App Store or TestFlight. A "release" binary from Xcode simply has release build settings (optimisation, stripping debug symbols etc) applied. It is not signed by apple.

Comment: Okay... thank you. I'll try with TestFlight then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by Paulw11, need to distribute app through TestFlight (or Appstore). In TestFlight, added my id (as a tester) and then downloaded the actual release app signed from Apple (This is another process as Apple validates your app before signing it and all issues pointed out must be addressed) in my testing device.

After this, I was able to connect to the production server.